# Make constructor to only accept objects with [Serializable] attribute in C#

Tags: c#, serialization, constructor, attributes, serializable

I want to modify my constructor so that it only accepts objects that have the `[Serializable]` attribute. Here is my current constructor code:

```
public MyClass(object obj)
{
}
```

I want to change it to something like this:

```
public MyClass(? obj)
{
}
```

How can I accomplish this in C#?

Comment: Are you sure? That [Serializable] stuff is quite old, we have better means now.

Comment: Short answer: You cannot do this compile time. Use reflection and throw an exception at runtime.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Can you please ne more specific?

Comment: @HenkHolterman About the other means?

Comment: Google "C# serialization" and pick through the results. JSon is popular lately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing that comes to my mind is to simplify this by allowing only objects that implement `ISerializable` interface:

```
public MyClass(ISerializable obj)
{
    // ...
}
```

But I think it's too simple, isn't it?

Alternatively:

```
public MyClass(Object obj)
{
    if (!Attribute.IsDefined(obj.GetType(), typeof(SerializableAttribute)))
        throw new ArgumentException("The object must have the Serializable attribute.","obj");

    // ...
}
```

I think that you can even check for it by using:

```
obj.GetType().IsSerializable;
```

Comment: `obj.GetType()` _is_ Reflection.

Comment: Err I mean, without using Attribute.IsDefined <_<

Comment: But my goal was to restrict it at compile time.

Comment: Well, you can't. There is absolutely NO WAY to accomplish this. You can find two good alternatives above.